# Custom Single Post Page for existing Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using the ACF Post Field, I have a page where I am displaying selected posts of Post Type Vegetable. Each post has the hyperlink to the Single post page for Vegetables but I am trying to use a different Single post page.

Current hyperlink uses single-vegetable.php

```
https://www.example.com/vegetable/broccoli
```

Desired hyperlink should use single-recipes.php

```
https://www.example.com/recipes/broccoli
```

ACF Code

```
$vegetables = get_field('vegetables');
if( $vegetables ): 
    foreach( $vegetables as $vegetable ): 
    ?>
        <div class="recipe">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> // This is the link I need to update
                <div class="recipe-image">
                    <?php
                    $featured_image = has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail() : '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/coming-soon.png" alt="Default Image">';
                    echo $featured_image;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <h3 class="recipe-title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php 
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The `single-*.php` file pattern is for CPTs. So just to confirm, you have two CPTs, one with a slug/name of `vegetable` and another with `recipes`, right? And also, you can guarantee that there’s a one-to-one relationship, so whenever someone adds a vegetable, they also add a corresponding recipe?

Comment: So you don't need to be able to access `/vegetable/broccoli` at all any more then? Or do you want those individual vegetable pages to still be available, and only have those specific hyperlinks point somewhere else, to the recipes, in this one specific location?

Comment: Your ACF loop is wrong - You aren't setting up the posts - So you are just taking the current link etc. not the loops. you could try `get_permalink($vegetable);`